# Put in the map if key exists and value is not null, else throw exception

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

```
void addToMapIfKeyExists(String k, String v) {
    if (!map.containsKey(k)) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException(k + " does not exist in the map");
    }

    // else ignore
    if (v != null) {
        map.put(k, v);
    }
}
```

Can I write this in a better way in Java 8? Can I merge it into one expression in some way?

Comment: @Kayaman, I have updated and changed the question a bit, any ideas?

Comment: default V replace(K key, V value)
Replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value.
Does not this work for you?

Comment: Be careful with replace. Check the explanation in “returns”

Comment: What you have already is good enough except for the exception handling when the value is `null`, it's just that the requirement seems a little weird. It's as if `putIfPresent` with exception handling to deviate from a normal `put` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, in a single statement:

```
public void overwrite(String k, String v) {
    map.compute(k, (key, value) -> {
        if (value == null) throw new NoSuchElementException(key + " does not exist in the map");
        return v == null ? value : v;
    });
}
```

The above does:

[1] if key is not in the map, or is mapped to null, it throws `NoSuchElementException`.

[2] Otherwise, will do nothing if you're trying to set `null`.

[3] otherwise, will set the key to the new value

Which is apparently what you want, but that's a bizarre combination of requirements.

Comment: Why do you say _bizarre_?

Comment: It's more atomic. _IF_ the map makes certain atomic guarantees, the above will be atomic. an if/else cannot be made atomic by the map, ever - it cannot know that a second call is forthcoming. The performance of these things depends on the VM, the OS, and especially the map impl, there is no one answer. For most maps, it won't make any performance difference.

Comment: It would make more sense if an update operation just writes if key is not in map. If it really has no only overwrite if it was already there, the null handling is weird: If I want to overwrite with null, then it should just do that (replace the value with null, or possibly, delete the value). Note that having compute return 'null' means: Delete.

Comment: An ordinary `HashMap` makes no atomicity guarantees, still a single `compute` could be more efficient than `containsKey` followed by `put`, as it bears only a single hash lookup. You could also use `if(map.compute(k, (key, value) -> v == null ? value : v) == null) throw new NoSuchElementException(key + " does not exist in the map");`; this variant would also work with `computeIfPresent`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the requirement is:

> Put in the map if key exists or value is not null, **else throw exception**

Which means:

- If key doesn't exist, throw exception
- If value is null, throw exception
- Put in the map

You should do the null check first, then use the [`replace(K key, V value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-) method and check the return value, so you only do the map lookup once.

```
void addToMapIfKeyExists(String k, String v) {
    if (v == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is null");
    if (map.replace(k, v) == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Key doesn't exist: " + k);
}
```

Comment: This would perform a `put` when the `key` is not already present and update the existing `Map`. Besides "*A `null` return can also indicate that the map previously associated `null` with the key..*"

Comment: @Naman That is true about `null` return value, but the requirement for the method would indicate that `null` values aren't allowed, which works perfectly for the newer methods on `Map`, like `replace()`, that treats `null` values as non-existing entries.

Comment: Agreed over the consideration made with the shared implementation aligning to the `null` value handling. But as a side effect of `replace`, updating the map beats the purpose of `addToMapIfKeyExists`.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest of the forms, as it reads, the following might suit your needs:

```
static void addToMapIfKeyExists(String k, String v) {
    if (v != null && map.containsKey(k)) { // if key exists and value is not null
        map.put(k, v); // Put in the map 
    } else { // else throw exception
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Else throwing exception.");
    }
}
```

---

**Disclaimer**: Decide wisely before choosing this. I would **NOT** recommend this as a practice based on the APIs involved.

```
static void addToMapIfKeyExistsOneLiner(String k, String v) {
    map.put(k, Optional.ofNullable(v)
            .filter(ignore -> map.containsKey(k))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new));
}
```

and I could compare the behavior of both these methods is the same using the following tests:

```
static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

private static void comparativeTest() {
    map.put("a", "trying");
    map.put("b", "crying");

    addToMapIfKeyExists("a", "works");
    System.out.println(map.get("a").equals("works"));

    addToMapIfKeyExistsOneLiner("a", "works");
    System.out.println(map.get("a").equals("works"));


    addToMapIfKeyExists("b", null); // null value throw exception
    addToMapIfKeyExists("e", "new key throws exception");

    addToMapIfKeyExistsOneLiner("b", null); // null value throw exception
    addToMapIfKeyExistsOneLiner("e", "new key throws exception");
}
```

Comment: So your answer to both questions is "No", i.e. the questions: *"Can I write this in a better way in Java 8?"* and *"Can I merge it into one expression in some way?"*, since this code is basically the same as the question code, except you fixed the exception throwing.

Comment: @Andreas I guess there is a way out for that as well. But mostly with an abuse of another API from the JDK. So not completely a "No" as much as I could say.

Comment: Thanks @Naman. Can you compare your one liner with the answer I accepted some hours ago?

Comment: @HarshalParekh I would suggest you write a unit test and assert based on the expectations comparing the various implementations here, then you can decide which suits your need with a readability as you would perceive.

Comment: @Naman, I meant performance, not accuracy. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HarshalParekh If you look at the code of `compute`, as in the `Map` interface => `V oldValue = get(key); V newValue = remappingFunction.apply(key, oldValue);`, it evaluates both the new and old value. The OP's code in the `remappingFunction` seems to be handling the exceptional cases and that should just be an extra `get` for you even when the value is `null` as compared to the code here.